# Generate PHP Documentation for different access levels

Tags: php, phpdoc, phpdocumentor2

I'm working in a php project that needs to generate 3 or more documentations, ones more restrictive than others. 
For documentation, I use PhpDocumentor 2. 
The only way I've found is for 2 level of documentation, using `@internal` tag and --parseprivate option (for generate a private documentation).

Is posible to generate a third documentation with an intermediate restriction level?

I've also tried `@access` tag with --visibility, but it doesn't work in version 2 of phpDocumentor. 
Or `@ignore` tag, but I didn't found a way to generate a third documentation with code setted with this tag.

Comment: Mmm, are there different files, folders that need to be parsed for the final access level? If so you can use the -d -f flags

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `@access` tag is a defunct PHP4 tag, to use before actual visibility keywords were added to PHP5.  PhpDocumentor 1.x would recognize the tags, but if the keywords were in the code, the tags would be ignored.  2.x doesn't even bother with those tags anymore.

"Intermediate level" is a rather arbitrary description.  All three "levels" here would need some particular requirements spelled out, and would likely be best managed by three different `phpdoc.xml` configuration files.

Here's an example of how I might describe three levels of docs, and how I'd accomplish them.

**API-level**:  I'd use a file-based argument to only document the *interfaces*.  If the `@api` tag is used in the docblocks to denote the actual individual pieces of the public API, then you could just rely on those.  However, I think the *presentation* of this info in the documentation is actually just a highlighting sidebar, whereas my approach of specifically documenting the interfaces means the whole document is solely the defined interfaces (which I presume to be "the API").

**App-level**:  I'd capture all classes, but go with the default behavior of only showing public visibility components.

**Dev-level**:  I'd use the --parseprivate to show all components.  I also do tend to put developer-targeted information into `@internal` tags myself.

Again, I'd use customized `phpdoc.xml` config files for each of these, so that my definitions could be committed to version control.

Answer (score 0):

This is an interesting question / issue. The ability to tailor the documentation to specific users.

I would check out [PHPFUI/InstaDoc](http://phpfui.com/?n=PHPFUI%5CInstaDoc). I wrote it because I was not satisfied with the current state of PHP documentation. It is a dynamic documentation viewer. It is perfect for developing PHP apps, as you have all the current documentation for the new code you are actually writing at the time, and all your old code, including code brought in via Composer. It reads the current file's doc blocks and dynamically renders the documentation. So before you check in your code, you can actually see the docs you included. Often looking at the docs, you find issues and things that can be fixed. So it makes for a great workflow.

It could easily be made to have access levels. Check it out and submit an issue or PR, pretty simple to add user controllable views. But your issue is exactly what InstaDoc was created for.  I hope you find it useful.